# how to convert com instance to variant, to pass it in idispach invoke

Tags: c++, com, activex, variant, idispatch

i want to pass a com object instance as a variant parameter to another active x object function, for that i need to convert the idispatch pointer to a variant? i am not sure.

```
hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    { 
        return;
    }
    hr = CLSIDFromProgID(objectName.c_str(), &clsid);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return;
    }
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pApp));
    if (FAILED(hr) || pApp == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
```

this is the instance creating code, after that i am using this :

```
VARIANT v;
    VariantInit(&v);
    v.pdispVal = pApp;
    v.ppdispVal = &pApp;
    v.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
    return v;
```

and passing it to an active x method, but it is giving access violation after invoke.
what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `ppdisVal`. Also, you probably need to call `pApp.AddRef()` when you wrap a `VARIANT` around it. Because a future call to `VariantClear` will end up calling `pdispVal->Release()`. The best with VARIANTs is to use the smart wrappers such as `_variant_t` or `CComVariant` provided by the Visual Studio environment. With these wrappers, you can just use equality operator.

Comment: ok, is there any reference for it? i will try to do it myself though

Comment: it in atl right? i cant use atl

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio? If yes, _variant_t needs comdef.h otherwise CComVariant needs atlcom.h

Comment: yes! i got it working! btw, using _variant_t and removing ppdisVal usage, also i am not able to call a function from a variant exception thrown in GetIDsOfNames

Comment: got it all working!! thanks man , add it as an answer, explaining a little bit and i will select it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the [VARIANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-tagvariant) raw structure, you can code it like this:

```
VARIANT v;
VariantInit(&v);
pApp->AddRef();
v.pdispVal = pApp;
v.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
...
// later on, some code (this code or another code) will/should call this
VariantClear(&v); // implicitely calls pdispVal->Release();
```

Or, if you're using the Visual Studio development environment, then you can just use the [_variant_t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-class?view=vs-2017) or [CComVariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomvariant-class?view=vs-2017) (ATL) smart wrappers which I recommend. In this case, you can just call it like this:

```
IDispatch *pApp = ...

// both wrappers will call appropriate methods
// and will release what must be, when destroyed
CComVariant cv = pApp;

// or

_variant_t vt = pApp;
```

PS: don't use *both* wrapper classes, make your choice. If a project uses ATL, I uses `CComVariant`, otherwise `_variant_t`, for example.